# Aggregate hours between two dates with IQueryable from DB

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have table with these columns:

```
id int, name string, startDate DateTime, endDate DateTime
```

I want to get from DB SUM of HOURS between these dates for all records.

I use `IQueryable`, but I don't know how correctly form the query..

```
public int GetSumOfHours(int? assignedProjectId)
{
    var query = GetAll(); //GetAll() returns IQueryable<T>, 

    if (assignedProjectId.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(solution => solution.AssignedProject.Id == assignedProjectId.Value);
    }

    // Get sum of hours  ----> query = query...??
}
```

Thanks for HELP !

Comment: this may help : https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/calling_sqls_datediff_function_in_linq_to_entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below.  Get seconds and then sum the seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable query = new DataTable();
            query.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            query.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            query.Columns.Add("startDate", typeof(DateTime));
            query.Columns.Add("endDate", typeof(DateTime));


            query.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "John", DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:0:12"), DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:1:12") });
            query.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "John", DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:3:12"), DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:5:12") });
            query.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Bob", DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:0:12"), DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:1:12") });
            query.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Bob", DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:0:12"), DateTime.Parse("1/1/1 0:1:12") });

            var totalSeconds = query.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("id") == 1)
                .Select(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("endDate") - x.Field<DateTime>("startDate")).TotalSeconds).Sum();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some math and the `Sum()` method:

```
public class hours
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
List<hours> allHrs = new List<hours>{
    new hours{Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3.2), End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)},
    new hours{Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3.9), End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2.03)},
    new hours{Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3.8), End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2.9)}
};

//Project a new collection with the math done for number of minutes in each row
var mins = from h in allHrs
    select new {nbrMinutes = (h.End - h.Start).Minutes};

//Sum all rows, divide by 60 to get hours
Double total = mins.Sum (s => s.nbrMinutes / 60.0 );

Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify *CrowCoder's* example to sum the hours directly using TimeSpan and methods `Subtract` and `TotalHours`:

```
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.Today;    
    List<hours> exampleHours = new List<hours>{
        new hours{Start = d.AddHours(-3.2), End = d.AddHours(-2)},
        new hours{Start = d.AddHours(-3.9), End = d.AddHours(-2.03)},
        new hours{Start = d.AddHours(-3.8), End = d.AddHours(-2.9)}
    };

    double totalHours = 
        (from h in exampleHours
        select new {allHours = (h.End.Subtract(h.Start).TotalHours)})
        .Sum(t => t.allHours);

    Console.WriteLine(totalHours.ToString());
}
```